# Could I debug Android app from remote server?

Tags: java, android, linux, debugging

In our company, we could not access the code from our PC`(IP:10.127.10.38)`, the codes are in a remote Linux server, there are connective. I have read how to debug an app from local adt([here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html#debuggingPort)). But when I choose an VM from PC's ddms and trying to connect the 8700 port from remote Linux server, it always prompt "Faild to connect to remote VM. Connection refused". I want to know if I could do that remote debug in my remote Linux server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can debug remotely and this link contains step by step tutorial to debug remotely.

**[step by step tutorial to debug android app remotely](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)**

[Maybe this can help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Running_and_Debugging_Your_Android_Application_Remotely)

Comment: Thanks Bedi, but I want to debug Android apps, not web apps. I don't know how to forward the debug port(8700) as a connective port from  the eclipse on remote Linux server.

Comment: see the other link @user2427790